# Replacing a brush color in WNDCLASS

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm reading Petzold's book and stuck on following piece of code which I simply can't understand what is does.

the author says:

> You can create the new brush and insert the handle in the window class
>   structure and then delete the brush.

```
DeleteBrush((HBRUSH)
    SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR)
        CreateSolidBrush(RGB(color[0], color[1], color[2]))));
```

`SetClassLongPtr()` sets a new brush, but I can't understand how is  `DeleteBrush()` deleting old brush, if parameter is a new brush which we are going to use.

it looks like new brush replaced the old brush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SetClassLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589.aspx) returns the current/old brush:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the previous value of the specified offset. If this was not previously set, the return value is zero.

To understand the code better, it can be rewritten as:

```
HBRUSH hNew = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(color[0], color[1], color[2]))));
HBRUSH hOld = (HBRUSH) SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG_PTR) hNew);
DeleteBrush(hOld);
```

Comment: oh, it return *previous value*, that makes sense now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is incomplete, hBrush is either coming from a prior call to GetClassLongPtr or is left over from window class registration (it doesn't matter in either case). The window class has a slot for the brush to use, that slot is what SetClassLongPtr writes to so it doesn't matter whether the delete precedes or follows the SetClassLongPtr.

Basically think of window class registration as holding a collection of structures similar to WNDCLASSEX itself (I suspect there is internal information as well but that is only supposition and also doesn't matter), SetClassLongPtr writes to that collection.

Comment: That is not correct. The code is complete, and `SetClassLongPtr` returns the previous brush, that needs to be cleaned up. I don't understand the upvote on an answer, that doesn't even address the question.